# Interleave two strings of different length

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I have two string a and b, length of b is half of length of a, I tried to create a loop to put on character of b every 2 character of a I tried this

```js
let a = "pekaoo";
let b = "eb!";
let stop = a.length;
for (let i = 1; i <= stop; i += 2) {
    a = a.substring(0,i) + b[i/2] + a.substring(i);
}

console.log(a);
```

which is supposed to show 'peekaboo! but don't work

Comment: a.stop means nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replace()`

```js
let a = "pekao";
let b = "eb!";

let arr = [...b]
let res = a.replace(/.{1,2}/g, match => match + arr.shift())

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the string with single letters and slice the longer string by using a factor of two.

Thenn add all parts to a new string.

```js
let a = "pekaoo",
    b = "eb!",
    result = '';

for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    result += a.slice(i * 2, (i + 1) * 2) + b[i];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: as always a laconic solution!

Answer (score 1):

For your very specific request, I was able to write the following code that seems to work. Should also work with larger strings (you'll have to make some minor changes then).

```js
let a = "pekaoo";
let b = "eb!";
var outcome = "";

for(let i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++) {
    outcome += a.substring((i*2),((i+1)*2)) + b.substring(i, i+1);
}

console.log(outcome)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = "pekaoo";
let b = "eb!";

let result = "";

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    result += a[i];

    if ((i - 1) % 2 == 0){
    result += b[(i - 1) / 2]
    }
    
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

And using [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) instead of [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```js
const a = "pekaoo",
      b = "eb!";
let res = "";

for (let i = 0; i <= a.length; i += 2) {
    res += a.substr(i, 2) + b.substr(i/2, 1);
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may look like much, but it is a more algorithmic approach to the solution.

1. First you will need to identify the longest word, because this will drive your reducer array.
2. Now while you reduce each character position, you will reduce each string:

   - If current string length is equal to the longest string, then you just return the character at the global index.
   - Else, if the modular of the global index and the ratio of the current string is 1, return the character offset by the ratio of the current string.

```js
const longestArr = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b);
const interleave = (...strArr) => {
  let longest = longestArr(strArr),
      ratios = strArr.map(s => Math.floor(longest.length / s.length));
  return longest.split('').reduce((r, _, globalIndex) => {
    return strArr.reduce((r1, s, localIndex) => {
      let ratio = ratios[localIndex];
      if (ratio === 1) {
        return r1 + s.charAt(globalIndex); // Default case
      } else {
        if (globalIndex % ratio === 1) {
          return r1 + s.charAt(Math.floor(globalIndex / ratio));
        } else {
          return r1;
        }
      }
    }, r);
  }, '');
}

console.log(interleave('pekabo!', 'eo'));
console.log(interleave('pekaoo', 'eb!')); // Use-case
console.log(interleave('pko', 'eao', 'eb!'));
console.log(interleave('pa', 'eb', 'eo', 'ko', '!'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```